# Sum and average of numbers within an array C

Tags: c

I'm confused on how to calculate the mean and the sum of the numbers within an array, I can generate the numbers but the program keeps crashing. I'm very new to arrays and pointers any help/information helps. thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int sum(int *myInts)
{
    int sum=0,i;

    for(i=0; i < 20; i++){
        sum += myInts[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int mean(int *myInts)
{
    int mean=0,i;

    for(i=20; i < 20; i++){
        mean += myInts[i] / 20;
    }
    return mean;
}

int main(int i)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int *myInts[20];

    for(i=0; i < 20 ; i++){
        myInts[i] = rand() % 15;
    }
    printf("The array is: ");
    for(i=0; i < 20; i++){
        printf(" %d", myInts[i]);
    }
    printf("\nThe sum of the array is: %d", sum(myInts[20]));
    printf("\nThe mean of the array is: %d", myInts[20],mean(myInts[20]));

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int *myInts[20];` should be `int myInts[20];`

Comment: `for(i=20; i < 20; i++)` isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Thank you for the correction, but the program is still crashing. I forgot to mention that a lot of the math is screwed up

Comment: Do you really mean for the mean to return an int?  Typically, a mean would be represented as a floating point type.

Comment: I'd calculate the mean by summing *first* (probably by calling `sum()`), *then* dividing by the array size. Since all your values are less than 20, you're just summing a bunch of zeroes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int *myInts[20];
```

Here, you've declared an array of **pointers to int**, not an array of int.  Within the `main` function you get away with it because integers can be converted to pointers and back, but it becomes an issue when you call the function:

```
sum(myInts[20])
```

This passes the array element with offset 20 to the function.  Because array indexes start with 0, an array of size 20 has indexes from 0 to 19.  So you read past the end of the array, then in the function this value it treated as a pointer and dereferenced.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is what causes the crash.

You instead want to declare an array of `int`:

```
int myInts[20];
```

And pass the array to the function:

```
sum(myInts);
```

Comment: Thank you so much I got it to work, I have a question. When should I use pointers?